# i need an explanation about how this update code works (Laravel)

Tags: laravel

```
public function editCategory(Request $request,$id = null){//we pass the $id
    if($request->isMethod('post')){
        $data = $request->all();
        Category::where(['id'=>$id])->update(['name'=>$data['category_name'],
            'description'=>$data['description'],'url'=>$data['url']]);
        return redirect('/admin/view-categories')->with('flash_message_success','Category Updated Successfully');
    }

    $categoryDetails = Category::where(['id'=>$id])->first();  return view('admin.categories.edit_category')->with(compact('categoryDetails'));
```

}
//this code is working in my controller

Comment: How you call this action?

Comment: in my view record balde file, in my edit button i call this one {{url('/admin/edit-category/'.$category->id) }}

Comment: and in my edit.blade.php i call this on my form action {{url('/admin/edit-category/'.$categoryDetails->id) }}

Comment: See [How to handle "Explain this code" questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894/how-to-handle-explain-how-this-code-dump-works-questions) on [meta], for an explanation of why questions of this type are generally outside the site's rules (specifically, "too broad"). The stack of questions about how a given piece of code works is nearly unending -- one could dive as low as explaining the Java bytecode, or even lower, explaining the hardware assembly it compiles into, and have no assurance that that answer will address your *actual* question

Comment: ...without that question being made more specific and narrow than just a request for "an explanation".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply there are two ways to invoke this action:

- **Request in HTTP POST method**

  if you make a request to the URL `/admin/edit-category/12345` in HTTP `POST` method 
  then you make an update of the model called `Category` with `id = $id` (in my example 
  $id is 12345) and then you will be redirected in `/admin/view-categories` with a flash 
  message variable valorized with `Category Updated Successfully`
- **Request in HTTP GET method** (or any other HTTP method)

  if you make a request to the URL `/admin/edit-category/12345` in HTTP `GET` method then the action responds with a view of the model `Category` with `id = $id` (in my example $id is 12345) and put the fields of the model in the view params.

Comment: thank you sir,can i ask last one, what is the pupose of this code ' first(); '

Comment: Takes the first line found in DB with id = $id.

Answer (score 0):

ok i will explain to you this is edit fonction so it make modification of data stored in database

```
if($request->isMethod('post')){//if your data submitted to database
        $data = $request->all();//recupration of all information
        Category::where(['id'=>$id])->update(['name'=>$data['category_name'],
            'description'=>$data['description'],'url'=>$data['url']]);//change description , categoryname and url
        return redirect('/admin/view-categories')->with('flash_message_success','Category Updated Successfully')//and return seccess alert in your view;
    }

    $categoryDetails = Category::where(['id'=>$id])->first();  return view('admin.categories.edit_category')->with(compact('categoryDetails'));
```

Comment: you are welcom:)

Answer (score 0):

```
public function editCategory(Request $request,$id = null){//we pass the $id
//check that the request is a POST request
if($request->isMethod('post')){

    //Okay so it is, now store all request parameter in it's own variable
    $data = $request->all();

    //Access the Eloquent model Category, checks the id and updates 
    //accordingly
    Category::where(['id'=>$id])->update(['name'=>$data['category_name'],
        'description'=>$data['description'],'url'=>$data['url']]);

    //Return redirect to view-categories with a success message
    return redirect('/admin/view-categories')->with('flash_message_success','Category Updated Successfully');
}

//check the first id and return the view with the details, this would only be hit if the above if statement wasn't (wasn't a POST request for example)
$categoryDetails = Category::where(['id'=>$id])->first();  return view('admin.categories.edit_category')->with(compact('categoryDetails'));
```